# Facebook like - is there an URL you can call to sumbit "Like"? (without FBML or iframes)

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to add "Facebook Like" functionality to page **without** using **FBML** or **iframe**. Because i found this for the "Share" button i thought it's a pretty lightweight solution:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location=%22http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.location)+%22&#38;t=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" title="Share on Facebook..."><img src="/path/to/your/image/" width="12" height="12" alt="alt" /></a>
```

Basically it redirects user to:

```
http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=$url
```

So I want a javascript function to call (or more precisely : an URL you can call) to submit my "like".

Comment: whats your question? you have the url

Comment: Well, when i share then it counts as "share", not "like". Request the url with http://graph.facebook.com/http://example.com and it returns "shares" not "likes". But shares is something way different than likes, because "shares" will increment even if someone doesn't press on my button, but share the shared message. Read here: http://faso.com/fineartviews/21028/facebook-like-button-count-inaccuracies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, i didn't find an url you can submit to "like" a page. Looks like we have to use FBML or iframe solution to "like" something.

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript function you could call from anywhere in your page to **share**

```
<script>
function likeMyPage()
{
  window.open("http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+window.location.href);
}
</script>
```

This html button triggers the function

```
<button onclick="javascript:likeMyPage();" value="Do you Like me?" />
```

**Liking a page**

The following page allows you to generate the button for you:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

if you get the hand of the generated code snippet, i think you could implement it in your own. but can't see why you would do that, the facebook like generator does it for you.

Comment: The thing is i want to avoid facebook button within iframe or with FBML, is that it renders slooowly...

Comment: Can't you "steal" the code it generates, and create your own button / method with it ?